# String comparison using .equals() does not work in Java.

Tags: java, string-comparison

When comparing a string taken from console input to a string inside an array, it is always `false` unless I add `.toString()`. Both strings are equal and it should work without adding the `.toString()`. Can anyone help me figure out why?

Here I get the string I want to compare from the console:

```
System.out.println("\nEnter the name you wish to remove from the list.");
String name = in.nextLine();
System.out.println("\n\"" + myNameList.remove(new MyOrderedList(name)) + "\"" + " removed from the name list\n");
```

Here is the remove method:

```
public T remove(T element) {
    T result;
    int index = find(element);

    if (index == NOT_FOUND) {
        throw new ElementNotFoundException("list");
    }

    result = list[index];
    rear--;

    /** shift the appropriate elements */
    for (int scan = index; scan < rear; scan++) {
        list[scan] = list[scan+1];
    }

    list[rear] = null;
    return result;
}
```

Here is the find method that is were the problem is:

```
private int find(T target) {
    int scan = 0, result = NOT_FOUND;
    boolean found = false;

    if (!isEmpty()) {
        while (!found && scan < rear) {
            if (target.equals(list[scan])) { // Not sure why this does not work until I add the .toString()s
                found = true;
            }
            else {
                scan++;
            }
        }
    }

    if (found) {
        result = scan;
    }
    return result;
}
```

The `if (target.equals(list[scan]))` always returns `false` unless I change it to `if (target.toString().equals(list[scan].toString())`.

I am using an `ArrayList` to represent an array implementation of a list. The front of the list is kept at array index 0. This class is extended to create a specific kind of list if that helps. I can post all classes if needed.

Comment: Where is the definition of `list`?

Comment: I think it's due to generics - have a look at 'target' variable - is it really instance of String? Try to implement your own equals() and trace it...

Comment: Don't assume that because you can't use it, it's broken. If .equals() on String were broken, that would be pretty well known.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `myNameList` has a `String` generic parameter, then this will not work, because no `String` will equal a type of `MyOrderedList`.

If `myNameList` has a `MyOrderedList` generic parameter, then you will need to make sure that you define an `equals()` method for it.

Answer (score 3):

You are only using String.equals if the first argument is a String.

> String comparison using .equals() does not work java

It appears this is the thing which does work. Its T.equals() which doesn't work.

---

If you have this working, it means you have overridden `toString()` sensibly.

```
target.toString().equals(list[scan].toString()
```

but if this doesn't work

```
target.equals(list[scan])
```

it means you haven't overridden `equals(Object)` correctly.

Comment: you are doing injustice to us!!
you answer all the ques before we could even think of answers

Comment: a most grievous injustice indeed :)

Comment: @Yadnesh ok, ok, I will give it break. ;)

Comment: I will try to wait until the question is 10 mins old.

Comment: @PeterLawrey instead leave simple ones for us,while you tackling the biggies :D

Comment: @Eng.Fouad Cheers, you can come again. ;)

Comment: @Yadnesh I have trouble telling the difference.

Answer (score 0):

nicholas and peter are correct. i needed to override equals() method. I tried a few things and also let Eclipse generate the hashCode() and equals() to see what would happen and its working now without the .toString()

Here is what Eclipse generated for me:

```
    /* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see java.lang.Object#hashCode()
 */
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + ((myList == null) ? 0 : myList.hashCode());
    return result;
}

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see java.lang.Object#equals(java.lang.Object)
 */
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj) {
        return true;
    }
    if (obj == null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (!(obj instanceof MyOrderedList)) {
        return false;
    }
    MyOrderedList other = (MyOrderedList) obj;
    if (myList == null) {
        if (other.myList != null) {
            return false;
        }
    } else if (!myList.equals(other.myList)) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

I really thank everyone for such quick responses. I am fairly new to java so i read a lot of posts here when i run into a problem and i always find the answer here. Thanks everyone!